# Add new key for empty data object not working in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have question related to data of Vue.

I created data with an empty object.

```
data(){
 return {
    myObj: {}
 }
}
```

and function like this:

```
methods: {
  changeMyObj() {
    this.myObj.newKey = 'aaaa';
  }
}
```

Then I show it on template by click

```
  <a @click="changeMyObj">Click change</a>
     {{myObj.newKey}}
```

With this click, the nested key is not rendered on template. How can I resolve this issue?

Note: I do not meet this issue with Vuex or state of React.

Comment: myObj = {}  needs to be myObj : {} . Chage that and the code is good.

Comment: ah yes. it is my mistake while upload question, not related to issue above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of [vue.js reactivity](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html). In fact, here you are modifying a value that was not declared when the component mounted and Vue cannot track the changes.

---

You can update values by using the `Vue.set` method which allows Vue to track the data.

```js
Vue.set(this.myObj, "myKey", "Hello world")
```

---

You can also make a deep copy of the object instead of just adding the key.

This can be done using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

For example

```js
this.myObj = {...this.myObj, myKey: "Hello world"}
```

---

Here is a small example using the two versions

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    myObj: {}
  }),
  
  methods: {  
    addKey(){
      this.myObj = {...this.myObj, myKey: "Hello world foo"}
    },
    addKey2(){
      Vue.set(this.myObj, "myKey", "Hello world bar")
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ myObj.myKey }}
  <button @click="addKey">Add key</button>
  <button @click="addKey2">Add key 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this.

```
this.myObj = {...this.myObj, newKey:'aaaa'}
```

I do not think it is solution while it has no difference with:

```
this.myObj['newKey'] = 'aaaa';
or
this.myObj.newKey = 'aaaa';
```

If someone can explain why please let me know. Thanks

Comment: new properties added to object will not trigger changes

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to assign a new property in an existing object is `Vue.set(this.myObj, 'newKey', 'aaaa')` to make it reactive instead of `this.myObj.newKey = 'aaaa'`

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myObj: {}
  },
  methods: {
    changeMyObj() {
      Vue.set(this.myObj, 'newKey', 'aaaa')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="changeMyObj">Click change</button>
    {{ myObj.newKey }}
</div>
```